# Varying specific heat ratio in choked flow equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, gas

In the choked flow equation shown below there is gamma which is specific heat ratio $(C_p/C_v)$.

For Nitrogen, that value is $1.4$ in normal conditions. However at elevated pressures or temperatures, specific heat ratio changes significantly. For example, you can see [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/fluid.cgi?Action=Load&ID=C7727379&Type=IsoTherm&Digits=5&PLow=1&PHigh=301&PInc=50&T=300&RefState=DEF&TUnit=K&PUnit=bar&DUnit=kg%2Fm3&HUnit=kJ%2Fkg&WUnit=m%2Fs&VisUnit=uPa*s&STUnit=N%2Fm) that $C_p/C_v$ at $301 \ \mathrm{bar}$ and $300 \ \mathrm{Kelvin}$ is around $1.7$.

When the gas velocity is choked, the equation for mass flow rate is :

$$\ \dot{m} = C_dA \sqrt { \gamma \rho_0P_0\ \left ( \frac {2}{\gamma + 1} \right )  ^ \frac { \gamma + 1}{\gamma -1}}$$

Where,

$\dot{m}=$  Mass flow rate , in $kg/s$

$C_d=$ discharge coefficient, dimensionless

$A=$ Discharge hole cross-sectional area, in $m^2$

$\gamma =$ $\frac{C_p}{C_v} $ (Heat capacity ratio) of the gas

$C_p=$ Specific heat of the gas at constant pressure.

$C_v=$ Specific heat of the gas at constant volume.

$\rho_0=$ real gas (total) density at total pressure $P_0$ and total temperature $T_0$ , in $Kg/m^3$.

$P_0=$ absolute upstream total pressure of the gas , in $\mathrm{Pa}$ or $Kg/m.s^2$

$T_0=$ absolute upstream total temperature of the gas , in $K$

**My question :**  Should I take specific heat ratio constant as $1.4$ or should I change it dynamically by looking at its real value from tables?

Comment: This depends on the situation. What is the difference in m for the two values?

Comment: At 300 Bar and 300 Kelvin:
If k = 1.4 ==> m = 4.66
If k = 1.7 ==> m = 4.97
I have given arbitrary values for area and discharge coefficient for comparison. Density is found from NIST's website.

Comment: So now you have an estimate of the error you could potentially be making. It is for you to judge if that is acceptable or not.